# HTML draw vertical line across whole div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to draw a vertical line across a whole div following the mouse. The problem is that other elements are over the line. I want the line go over all content.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9hzcm23q/

And here the code:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('box');

var drawLines = function(event) {
  var x = event.pageX;
  var straightLine = element.querySelector('.straightLine');
  
  var slTrans = 'translate(' + x + 'px, 0px)';
  if(!straightLine) {
     straightLine = document.createElement('div');
     straightLine.classList.add('straightLine');
     straightLine.style.height = "100%";
     straightLine.style.width = '2px';
     element.appendChild(straightLine);
  }
  straightLine.style.transform = slTrans;
}

element.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
   drawLines(event);
});
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.straightLine {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box">
  <h1>
  Lorem
  </h1>
  <p>
  dolor amet
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `top: 0` to `straightLine` class like below:

```
.straightLine {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
}
```

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jc2ud9yx/)

Comment: You can add my fiddle if you want and I'll delete my answer since you beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

You can append it as the first child of the element instead at the end.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('box');

var drawLines = function(event) {
  var x = event.pageX;
  var straightLine = element.querySelector('.straightLine');
  
  var slTrans = 'translate(' + x + 'px, 0px)';
  if(!straightLine) {
     straightLine = document.createElement('div');
     straightLine.classList.add('straightLine');
     straightLine.style.height = "100%";
     straightLine.style.width = '2px';
     element.insertBefore(straightLine, element.firstChild)
  }
  straightLine.style.transform = slTrans;
}

element.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
   drawLines(event);
});
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.straightLine {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box">
  <h1>
  Lorem
  </h1>
  <p>
  dolor amet
  </p>
</div>
```